# Disable serverside MVC Validation if control is disabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Is it possible to disable a serverside MVC validation, if a textbox is disabled by client-side Javascript? Because, if I the textbox is disabled then there won't be any content in it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Is possible.
I have am answer for you: Remote Validation.
If you use the [Required] attribute and you dont fill the field, the ModelState will always respond as not valid. So a good alternative is using Remote Validation attribute.

I make this example for you:

**Model:**

```
 [Required]
 [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Only Numbers")]
 [Remote("CheckIfIsDisable", "Home", AdditionalFields = "TXTstatus", ErrorMessage = "You must to fill this field")]
 [DisplayName("Register Number")]
 public String bookId { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.bookId)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.bookId)
@Html.Hidden("TXTstatus", "enable")

<input type="button" onClick = "return disableTXT()" text="Toggle Disable/Enable bookId field"/>
```

*You must to put a javascript function to toggle the value:*

```
<script>
function disableTXT() {
if ($("#TXTstatus").val() === "enable") {
    $("#TXTstatus").val("disable");
    }
else {
    $("#TXTstatus").val("enable");
    }
}
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult CheckIfIsDisable(string bookId, string TXTstatus)
        {

            if (TXTstatus == "enable")
            {
        // This show the error message of validation
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
        // This will ignore the validation
               return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Is just an example. Feel free to change and adapt it to your needs. And feel free to ask.